# Monodromy action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

Let us consider the following tower of (finite) ramified Galois covers
$$S \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{P}_1 \xrightarrow{q} \mathbb{P}_1,$$
where $S$ is a Riemann surface. Denote by $R \subset \mathbb{P}_1$ the branch locus of $p$ and suppose that $q$ has no ramification points into $R$. Then the map
$$p_{|S-p^{-1}(R)}:S-p^{-1}(R) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_1-R$$
is an unramified cover. If we fix a point $x \in \mathbb{P}_1-R$ we have a transitive monodromy action of $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}_1-R)$ on the fiber $p^{-1}(x)$.

Now, denote by $r$ a point of $R$ and by $r'$ the point $q(r)$, and suppose that $q^{-1}(r') \subset R$. We can consider the inclusion $i: \mathbb{P}_1-R \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}_1-q^{-1}(r')$ and the corresponding induced homomorphism $$i_*:\pi_1(\mathbb{P}_1-R) \rightarrow \pi_1(\mathbb{P}_1 - q^{-1}(r')).$$
Is it true that $\ker{i_*}$ acts transitively (by monodromy) on the fiber $p^{-1}(x)$? If not, is there a counterexample of this?

Comment: If $R=q^{-1}(r')$ (which is easily achieved for arbitrary $p$, e.g. just pick $r'=0$ and $q$ as the polynomial map having exactly the points of $R$ as (simple) roots), isn't that kernel trivial?